# javax.naming.RefAddr not found by [83]

Tags: jdbc

When I tried reverse engineer my database:
database reverse engineer --testAutomatically --schema mydb

I had: javax.naming.RefAddr not found by [83]

I tried java 6 and 7

Please shed some light.

Thanks a lot in advance
James

Comment: if i run the command "database reverse engineer --testAutomatically --schema mydb" again,  I had new error:  Could not initialize class com.mysql.jdbc.Connection

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in STS.

To overcome this issue, add mysqlconnector jar in bundle folder before starting STS or eclipse. Than create new spring roo project and try to reverse engineer the database.

Thanks